# Docker permission problems when doing volume mapping

Tags: ubuntu, docker, permissions

I want to start a Jupyter notebook in a container. The requirement is that the notebooks that are created in the container should be also available on the host machine. For this I do volume mapping:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 -v $(shell pwd):/home/jovyan/work --name=notebook jupyter/base-notebook
```

When I run the above command, I receive the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/home/jovyan/work\") set in config.json failed: permission denied". ERRO[0000] error getting events from daemon: context canceled
```

To solve this problem temporarily, I changed the permissions of the current working directory on the host:

```
chmod a+rwx [current directory]
```

I thinks changing the permissions of the folders is not a good solution and there should be another problem.

Also I have to mention that I work in a company where I do not have sudo rights and we used a shared home directory.

Actually I have this problem with all images. For example:

```
docker run -it -v /net/home/abc/Desktop/:/etc ubuntu:16.04
```

returns the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\\"/var/lib/docker/containers/7e62c50efab7141468a00ddefb59d55715449e05f1c516662ac1f73fabab2722/resolv.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/e71d751ce8d253eafcd0dc5f41379cc4dd73da89302cfe8171becd228fba960e\\\" at \\\"/etc/resolv.conf\\\" caused \\\"lstat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/e71d751ce8d253eafcd0dc5f41379cc4dd73da89302cfe8171becd228fba960e/etc/resolv.conf: permission denied\\\"\"".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/base-notebook and notice the Docker Options. Per default this image has an unprivilieged user jovyan, with no permissions to your $pwd directory. 
Via ENV you might fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Also, make sure your docker user has access to the path you are trying to mount in your container.

In my case, my home directory had 700 permissions, so the docker user didn't have access to traverse the directory path. Giving read and execute permission allows the docker user to go through and mount correctly.